# Is there an upper bound for $\mathbb E(X\mid A)$ under constant $P(A)$?

Tags: probability

Let $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$ be a probability space and let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be a random variable with $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$.

Let $p\in(0,1)$.

> Can it be proved that the set $\{E[X\mid A]\mid A\in\mathcal A\wedge P(A)=p\}$ has an upper bound?

If my intuition is correct then:$$P(A)=P(X>a)\implies\mathbb E(X\mid A)\leq\mathbb E(X\mid X>a)\tag1$$
but I don't manage to find a formal proof for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb E[|X|] = \mathbb E[|X| \mid A]\; \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb E[|X| \mid A^c] \; \mathbb P(A^c) \ge \mathbb E[|X| \mid A]\; \mathbb P(A)$$
so $$\mathbb E[X \mid A] \le \mathbb E[|X| \mid A] \le \frac{\mathbb E[|X|]}{p}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That provides indeed an upper bound. Can anything be said about my intuition worded in (1)? It is based on the thought that under condition $X>a$ the values for $X$ are as high as possible. If it is correct then $\mathbb E(X\mid X>a)$ can even serve there as least upper bound, right?

Comment: Your answer is enough for the question in the title, so I accepted. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372042/169789) I posed a new question concerning my conjecture.