# Can it be proved that $P(A)=P(X>a)\implies\mathbb E(X\mid A)\leq\mathbb E(X\mid X>a)$?

Tags: probability

Let $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$ be a probability space and let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be a random variable with $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$.

In a [former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2371461/169789) I asked to provide an *upperbound* for the set: $$\{E[X\mid A]\mid A\in\mathcal A\wedge P(A)=p\}$$ where $p\in(0,1)$.

That question was answered properly but actually I longed for a confirmation of a conjecture that was mentioned in it. So this is **not** a duplicate of my former question. I would like to find a *least upperbound* for the set now.

---

If my intuition is correct then:
$$P(A)=P(X>a)\implies\mathbb E(X\mid A)\leq\mathbb E(X\mid X>a)\tag1$$
This because the condition $X>a$ is in a sense optimal for getting large values for $X$ (and in its wake the conditional expectation).

But I cannot find a proof for it, so am still uncertain. My questions are:

> Is $(1)$ correct? And - if so - can you provide a proof of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=[f>a]$, and let $B$ be some other set for which $P(B)=P(A).$  Clearly $P(A{\setminus}B)=P(B{\setminus}A).$ On $B{\setminus} A$ we have $f\le a$, and on $A{\setminus B}$ we have $f>a.$  So $$\int_{B\setminus A} f\,dP \le \int_{A\setminus B} f\,dP.$$ So $$\int_Bf\,dP\le\int_A f\,dP,$$ and since $P(A)=P(B)$  your result follows.

This is sometimes called the *Neyman-Pearson* or *water pouring* method, and your financial intuition (always invest in the most profitable options available) is correct.

Comment: That is a very nice confirmation of my conjecture. Thank you very much!